# Mongoose format datetime field in find query retrieving result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Need format ISO date time values using Mongoose with node.js

**MySQL Table Example**

[image: table example]

In MySQL we can format the date with select query itself. Below example for reference

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d/%m/%Y") AS formatted_date FROM TABLE_NAME where share_count>1
```

MongoDB Collection Documents Example

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ca6220f11b8212bc2c616f"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-26T14:20:16.667Z"),
    "booking_key" : "7O5YQY990",
     share_count : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ca6625cbcb601a209eda57"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-26T14:37:25.211Z"),
    "booking_key" : "3WW33HNO1",
     share_count : 3
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ca6761cc4b29077c21f5cd"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-09-26T14:42:41.725Z"),
    "booking_key" : "VT9QWWYO4",
     share_count : 0
}
```

Need to know how to format the `created_at` as like MySQL and retrieve list of result set

```
Collection.find({ share_count: {'$gte':1}}, function(err, resultset) {
});
```

**Expected Result**

```
/* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ca6220f11b8212bc2c616f"),
        "created_at" : "26/09/2017",
        "booking_key" : "7O5YQY990",
         share_count : 2
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ca6625cbcb601a209eda57"),
        "created_at" : "26/09/2017",
        "booking_key" : "3WW33HNO1",
         share_count : 3
    }

    /* 3 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ca6761cc4b29077c21f5cd"),
        "created_at" : "09/09/2017",
        "booking_key" : "VT9QWWYO4",
         share_count : 0
    }
```

Comment: The only thing that "alters" documents is either the `.aggregate()` or `.mapReduce()` methods. The aggregation framework in particular has methods to work with dates. The `.find()` method cannot alter document results. It can only select the properties to return and at most filter a "single" element to return from an array. It will not alter in any other way.